# Append table to String

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have two string as given below in C#

```
 string strEmail="<table id='tbl1'><tr><td>Green</td><td>Red</td></table>
    <table id='tbl3'><tr><td>Blue</td><td>Yellow</td></table>
    <table id='tbl4'><tr><td>Pink</td><td>White</td></table>";

    string tempAppend="<table id='tbl2'><tr><td>black</td><td>grey</td></table>";
```

Now, I want to append tbl2 immediately after tbl1?

How to do that in C#?

Please help me resolve the issue. Hopefully, it will be helpful for others as well.

Comment: I have a few questions; do you always know you have to insert between `tbl1` and `tbl3`, or could it be in various positions? Do the four tables always have the same contents? Is what you really want, to be able to have the tables sorted by their `id`?

Answer (score 3):

Use **StringBuilder**, Try this:

```
string strEmail="<table id='tbl1'><tr><td>Green</td><td>Red</td></table><table id='tbl3'><tr><td>Blue</td><td>Yellow</td></table><table id='tbl4'><tr><td>Pink</td><td>White</td></table>";
string tempAppend="<table id='tbl2'><tr><td>black</td><td>grey</td></table>";

StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(strEmail);

sb.Replace("<table id='tbl3'>",tempAppend +"<table id='tbl3'>");

strEmail = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: But, it will append at the end of the string i.e after tbl4. I want to append it right after tbl1.

Answer (score 0):

Use `StringBuilder`:

```
string strEmail = @"<table id='tbl1'><tr><td>Green</td><td>Red</td></table>
    <table id='tbl3'><tr><td>Blue</td><td>Yellow</td></table>
    <table id='tbl4'><tr><td>Pink</td><td>White</td></table>";

string tempAppend = @"<table id='tbl2'><tr><td>black</td><td>grey</td></table>";

var builder = new StringBuilder(strEmail);
var startPoint = "</td></table>";
var index = strEmail.IndexOf(startPoint);

builder.Insert(index + startPoint.Length, tempAppend);

strEmail = builder.ToString();
```

Comment: I haven't run the code, but won't this insert the entire table 2, inside table 1? It should be inserted after the end-tag of table 1, but that tag is identical to the other two.

Comment: @LarsKristensen your're right i misunderstood the answer on where insert the table.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately you can try this

```
string strEmail = "<table id='tbl1'><tr><td>Green</td><td>Red</td></table><table id='tbl3'><tr><td>Blue</td><td>Yellow</td></table><table id='tbl4'><tr><td>Pink</td><td>White</td></table>";
string tempAppend = "<table id='tbl2'><tr><td>black</td><td>grey</td></table>";
var inx = strEmail.IndexOf("<table id='tbl3'>");
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(strEmail);

stringBuilder.Insert(inx, tempAppend);
strEmail = stringBuilder.ToString();
```